# Drupal Webform - Send and then delete attachment

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-webform

I saw [this topic](http://drupal.org/node/159678) to send an attachment file in an email but I dislike because it edits a template.php while I would do a custom module for this.

I have a webform with a file field for send personal CV. Now I want it so that that after the form submission the file can be attached within the email and immediately delete it from the server for privacy purposes...

I think that this is possible with a hook but I'm a PHP beginner...

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful to look into the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and trigger modules.  I'm not an expert on rules, but it seems like a pretty straightforward use case and no programming is required

I provided the link for rules  Trigger is in core and can be enabled on the modules page.

Comment: I wouldn't use other modules...I like write a custom module that is more light